# Using a case class with map and nested case class with gremlin scala

Tags: scala, gremlin, janusgraph

How to write `new Marshallable` for the below [case class](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/master/gremlin-scala/src/test/scala/gremlin/scala/MarshallableSpec.scala#L23).

```scala
case class CCWithLabelAndId(
  s: String,
  @id id: Int,
  l: Long,
  o: Option[String],
  seq: Seq[String],
  map: Map[String, String],
  nested: NestedClass)
```

Taken from `MarshallableSpec` from `gremlin-scala` library. `Seq` and `Option` works without creating `new Marshallable` as explained in the documentation.

Also what should be cardinality and datatype for map and nested classes when defining the schema of such vertexes.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are not supported out of the box, because they don't have an underlying representation in the graph. There's only `Cardinality.[single|list|set]` in Tinkerpop3.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a way to serialise a Map or a nested case class to JSON string(using Circe or any json libs) and persist/retrieve using Marshallable. What is your recommendation on persisting non-primitive types like this?